# How to cast ViewState to List<Object>

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, nullreferenceexception

I have the following class, of which I want to store a list inside a ViewState.

```
[Serializable]
public class Project
{
    public string projectID { get; set; }
    public string workerID { get; set; }
    public string nameProject{ get; set; }

    public Project(string pid, string wid, string npro)
   {
      projectID = pid;
      workerID = wid;
      nameProject= npro;
  }
}
```

Within my `aspx` I have the following method that fills a list with the projects that I get from a `DataTable`. I finally store the list in a `ViewState` for later use.

```
private void fillList(DataTable dt)
{
    List<Project> projects = new List<Project>();

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string pid = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
        string wid = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
        string npro = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();

        projects.Add(new Project(pid, wid, npro));
    }

    ViewState["Projects"] = new List<Project>();
    ViewState["Projects"] = projects;
}
```

Now I want to retrieve the `list` stored in the `ViewState`, to perform other actions. This is what I have tried.

```
protected void btnRetreive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                
    List<Project> data = (List<Project>)ViewState["Projects"];

    Response.Write(data.Count);   
}
```

But when I run it I get the following error

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   App_Web_vwe5qgkl.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: inside fillList(DataTable dt) method what is that proyectos ?

Comment: Hi, actually it is projects

Comment: In which line NRE has thrown? Seems that your `ViewState` assignment and retrieval working for me with bare string values (without `DataTable`). There must be something messed up, check `data` variable content first.

Comment: Hi  Tetsuya Yamamoto, the error is thrown in the line Response.Write(data.Count);   I don't know where is the error =(

Comment: Resolved. Thanks for replying, the error was elsewhere.